# Differences between editions of "Walk through Combinatorics"

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

Other than changing the date from $2003$ in a pigeon-hole Example $1.2$ to $2023$, are there any substantive reasons to upgrade from the $2$nd edition to the $4$th or $5$th editions.

(Sounds like a iPhone question)